# Storing shopping cart for guest user using spring session and spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, e-commerce, spring-session

I am new to spring session and spring security. I am developing an e-commerce application. My application will not have logged in user.So whenever a user lands on my application I need to create a session to this user and whenever the user adds item to the cart it should store in session.On Checkout i will store this cart items into the database.I could acheive this functionality by servlets using HTTPsession but as per my knowledge using httpsession is not good practice.So i am planning to implement it in spring session and spring security.My question is i dont have authenticated user so is it possible for spring security to create session for anonymous user.I am using HeaderHttpSessionStrategy

For example i am calling "localhost:8080/token" from my app which creates a session id and send to my client.i store the response session id in my localstorage and planning to send this sessionid as X-Auth-token to my headers from next request.If i do so i dont have any authentication configured in my security config as i dont have logged in user.While implementing my cart do i need to get this request header and store it in session so that session is maintained and cart is saved and retreived from session. Will this create me new session for each new user ?.Or else if i dont have logged in user is it ok to implement HttpSession using servlet?. Please let me know with this code whether my session is stored in redis database or not?Please suggest me way or sample to implement my functionality in efficient way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/css/**", "/js/**", "/image/**", "/book/**", "/user/**", "/**" };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS)
                .permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();

    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}
```

HttpSessionConfig.java

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    }

}
```

Comment: Spring session creates a session ID for each user, whether he is authenticated or not. Maybe you need to link your cart to session by this ID.